# VueJS reactivity issue for object inside array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've declared my data object as `queuedItemList: []` which is supposed to contain an array of items provided by a background service. After the HTTP request, I populate the list using a for loop like

```
for(var i = 0; i < getList.length; i++) {
    var newObject = Object.assign({}, getList[i]);
    this.queuedItemList.splice(i, 1, newObject);
}
```

which is used to populate the following template

```
<Item v-for="(item, index) in queuedItemList" :key="index" :componentData="item" :index="index" @remove="removeItem">
</Item>
```

I am supposed to do a periodic HTTP GET to get the new list of items, which may also contain current items with maybe different state. Inside the component, I am using a `v-if` to select between two different icons.

```
<v-icon name="play" class="controlIcons" v-if ="playControl" />
<v-icon name="pause" class="controlIcons" v-if ="!playControl" />
```

Now, after some HTTP requests, I see the value of `playControl` change in Vue Devtools which confirms that the actual value is reflected in the component. However, I can't see the icons change due to the change in the value of `playControl`. Furthermore, everything works as expected if I refresh the screen.

My guess is that I'm messing up the reactivity somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

```
for(var i = 0; i < getList.length; i++) {
    var newObject = Object.assign({}, getList[i]);
    this.$set(this.queuedItemList, i, newObject);
}
```

Another method might be to update the parent's item list :key - thus, rerendering it - everytime you add an item:

```
</div :key="computedKey">    
    <Item v-for="(item, index) in queuedItemList" :key="index" :componentData="item" :index="index" @remove="removeItem"></Item>
</div>
```

With

```
computed: {
    computedKey () {
        return this.queuedItemList.length
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the key method work even if the length of the array doesn't change?

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work for me. Do I need to add a watcher somewhere?

Comment: The length needs to change, but this.$set should have done the trick :o

Comment: It did the trick, its just that my watcher on the other end was kind of broken. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the structure of "playcontrol"

```
<v-icon name="play" class="controlIcons" v-if ="playControl" />
```

I passed by something similar in past, when you update "playControl" value, you do just "playControl = newValue"? If you do, this can screw up the reactivity, try use Vue $set directive, like:

```
Vue.set(this.playControl, <value>);
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#vm-set-changed

Comment: But `playControl` is just a boolean variable which is assigned like `this.playControl = ['NotStarted', 'Stopped', 'Paused'].includes(this.componentData.State);` during the creation. I'm not sure if that will work but I'll still give it a try.

Comment: I tried that, and I get `"TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got boolean"`

Comment: hmmmm, okey, once i need to force a component to refresh the code, Vue offers, "this.$forceUpdate()" try it after get the new list of items;

https://br.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#vm-forceUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I needed was a combination of setters and watchers. I used @alx.lzt's setters and a watcher on the component level and that solved everything

Answer (score 0):

You can use several properties for reactivity check, `$set` to change the property in an object, `$nextTick` to assign the value.

If the both don't work you may try `$forceUpdate()`